# Fatal Error Exception in Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this problem with a Laravel 5.1 app. The PHP version is 5.6.16.
What am I doing wrong?

> FatalErrorException in d4c2ea460399317ac416d4c481ae27fb line 75: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

```html
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<?php /**/ usort($tableGrid, "SiteHelpers::_sort") /**/ ?>

<div class="page-content row">
  <!-- Page header -->
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-title">
      <h3> <?php echo e($pageTitle); ?> <small><?php echo e($pageNote); ?></small></h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('dashboard')); ?>"> Dashboard </a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <?php echo e($pageTitle); ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="page-content-wrapper m-t">

    <div class="sbox animated fadeInRight">
      <div class="sbox-title">
        <h5> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </h5>
        <div class="sbox-tools">
          <a href="<?php echo e(url($pageModule)); ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-white tips" title="Clear Search"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Clear Search </a>
          <?php if(Session::get( 'gid')==1): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('sximo/module/config/'.$pageModule)); ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-white tips" title=" <?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_config')); ?>"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sbox-content">
        <div class="toolbar-line ">
          <?php if($access[ 'is_add']==1): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('regate/update')); ?>" class="tips btn btn-sm btn-white" title="<?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_create')); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle "></i>&nbsp;
            <?php echo e(Lang::get( 'core.btn_create')); ?>
          </a>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if($access[ 'is_remove']==1): ?>
          <a href="javascript://ajax" onclick="SximoDelete();" class="tips btn btn-sm btn-white" title="<?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_remove')); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle "></i>&nbsp;
            <?php echo e(Lang::get( 'core.btn_remove')); ?>
          </a>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to( 'regate/search')); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-white" onclick="SximoModal(this.href,'Advance Search'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</a>    
          <?php if($access[ 'is_excel']==1): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('regate/download?return='.$return)); ?>" class="tips btn btn-sm btn-white" title="<?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_download')); ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-download"></i>&nbsp;
            <?php echo e(Lang::get( 'core.btn_download')); ?>
          </a>
          <?php endif; ?>

        </div>



        <?php echo Form::open(array( 'url'=>'regate/delete/', 'class'=>'form-horizontal' ,'id' =>'SximoTable' )); ?>

        <div class="table-responsive" style="min-height:300px;">
          <table class="table table-striped ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="number">No</th>
                <th>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" />
                </th>

                <?php foreach($tableGrid as $t): ?>
                <?php if($t[ 'view']=='1' ): ?>
                <?php $limited=i sset($t[ 'limited']) ? $t[ 'limited'] : ''; ?>
                <?php if(SiteHelpers::filterColumn($limited )): ?>

                <th>
                  <?php echo e($t[ 'label']); ?>
                </th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <th width="70">
                  <?php echo e(Lang::get( 'core.btn_action')); ?>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php foreach($rowData as $row): ?>
              <tr>
                <td width="30">
                  <?php echo e(++$i); ?>
                </td>
                <td width="50">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value='<?php echo e($row->); ?>' />
                </td>
                <?php foreach($tableGrid as $field): ?>
                <?php if($field[ 'view']=='1' ): ?>
                <?php $limited=i sset($field[ 'limited']) ? $field[ 'limited'] : ''; ?>
                <?php if(SiteHelpers::filterColumn($limited )): ?>
                <td>
                  <?php if($field[ 'attribute'][ 'image'][ 'active']=='1' ): ?>
                  <?php echo SiteHelpers::showUploadedFile($row->$field['field'],$field['attribute']['image']['path']); ?>

                  <?php else: ?>
                  <?php /**/ $conn=( isset($field[ 'conn']) ? $field[ 'conn'] : array() ) /**/ ?>
                  <?php echo SiteHelpers::gridDisplay($row->$field['field'],$field['field'],$conn); ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td>
                  <?php if($access[ 'is_detail']==1): ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('regate/show/'.$row->.'?return='.$return)); ?>" class="tips btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="<?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_view')); ?>"><i class="fa  fa-search "></i></a>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php if($access[ 'is_edit']==1): ?>
                  <a href="<?php echo e(URL::to('regate/update/'.$row->.'?return='.$return)); ?>" class="tips btn btn-xs btn-success" title="<?php echo e(Lang::get('core.btn_edit')); ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i></a>
                  <?php endif; ?>


                </td>
              </tr>

              <?php endforeach; ?>

            </tbody>

          </table>
          <input type="hidden" name="md" value="" />
        </div>
        <?php echo Form::close(); ?>

        <?php echo $__env->make('footer', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.do-quick-search').click(function() {
      $('#SximoTable').attr('action', '<?php echo e(URL::to("regate/multisearch")); ?>');
      $('#SximoTable').submit();
    });

  });
</script>

<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.app', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

[View code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/V6xwLvmS)

Comment: in your code you missed here on line 75 `<?php echo e($row-> ????? ) ?>`

Comment: Issue is that row->$field['field'] u missed it in the this line

Comment: I can see more problem here. I don't know if it exist in you real code or not. Here is `$limited=i sset($t[ 'limited'])` it should `$limited=isset($t[ 'limited'])`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error could happen because of missing primary key at the table your module use. So check if your table has primary key. If not, create it and then create the module again.